# Thymeleaf CSS isn't loading

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm aware that problems like this were posted hundred of times. But i couldn't find similar things.

My web page based on thymeleaf doesn't load static contents. App is running on Spring Boot. It's something wrong with paths declared in html?

Below my resources paths:

```
-resources
--static
---css
---img 
---js 
---etc.
```

And a sample of head of the page :

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon"  th:href="@{/img/express-favicon.png}" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>RedCaynne Re</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link  th:href="@{/vendors/material-icon/css/materialdesignicons.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/linears-icon/style.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">

        <link  th:href="@{/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/revolution/css/layers.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/revolution/css/navigation.css}" rel="stylesheet">

        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bootstrap-selector/bootstrap-select.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/bootatrap-date-time/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link th:href="@{/vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css}" rel="stylesheet">

        <link  th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  th:href="@{/css/responsive.css}" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Do you have any spring security in your app? Is your project got build properly?  if possible add more code to your question like your application.properties.

Comment: I had a spring security in app but ive commented it in pom.xml and after that ive used mvn clean install. Project is building properly. application.properties file is empty.  Code has only simple controller, and 2 entities.

Comment: Need more information... if you look at the network tab in the developer, what does it say for each of those files?  What is the actual generated url when you view source?  What is your configuration of the resources (and why do you have `/vendor` when that doesn't appear in your resource paths?

Comment: add your code here. As s sample your code should looks like this https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/tree/master/ch02/tacos

Comment: In developer tools in chrome I can see error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). I have a /vendor path in my static resources (etc.).  I've posted source code on github. Link: https://github.com/lukkre002/jm
.

Comment: @Fayrant your code works perfectly fine I cannot add screenshot here.. I will add it in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Code works fine.

For code details refer to  https://github.com/srikantha2/jm
(this is forked from your OP code)

[image]

Comment: That's weird. I've cloned it from your's folked repo and it works fine now... :o